# Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET 5 WebApi to a remote server (Windows server 2008 R2) and am having trouble getting it to run correctly with IIS.

project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "App.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "App.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "App.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
    "App.ViewModel": "1.0.0-*",
    "AutoMapper": "4.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication": "1.0.0-rc2-16009",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-16009",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-16136",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc2-15873",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc2-16377",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-16017",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc2-15932",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-15916",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-15666",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-15644",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-15644",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "2.0.0-rc1-211120828"
  },

  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

when I try to access to the application from the browser, I get no response. And when I execute `web.cmd` on the server, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Ke
strel'. Available commands: kestrel, web.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. (Exception
 de HRESULT : 0x80070002)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)

   à System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadFile(String assemblyPath)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemb
lyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemb
lyName)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyNam
e)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name
, Func`2 factory)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName asse
mblyName)
   à Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, Res
olveEventArgs args)
   à System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String as
semblyFullName)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: 1. Do not mix rc1 and rc2 packages. That's a recipe for disaster :) 2. What DNX version do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using 1.0.0-rc2-16177 clr x86 version. 
The application runs very well on IIS Express!

Comment: I just saw something that looks like this a moment ago myself... did you run `dnvm upgrade`? That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you have all the dependencies installed on target server. Run `dnu list` in cmd to see all the project dependencies.

If some of them are not installed (they will appear red) run `dnu restore` to restore all packages.

You can also make sure that your project builds successfully by running `dnu build`

Hope it helps..