# unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel' Publish website on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, .net-core-rc1

I am getting following error while running the publish asp.net core RC1 website on the Windows Server using web.cmd,

Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'

The publish website has runtime included. 
Here is my project.json file,

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "DocX": "1.0.0.19",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "iTextSharp": "5.5.9",
    "itextsharp.pdfa": "5.5.9",
    "itextsharp.xtra": "5.5.8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "WebApi.Core": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Messaging": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Transactions": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

The publish content has a dependency 'WebApi.Core' which is added as a nuget package. Actually its a another class library project in my solution.

I have tried dnu restore but it is giving problem for the WebApi.Core dependency.

Same publish content is running fine on my Windows 10 local machine. 
Please let me know if you guys have any solution to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the global.json file from the hosted folder. It would be at approot or at approot\src[projectName].
If that doesn't work, try running the commands dnu list, dnu restore, dnu build
as per this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34212116/2168359

Comment: But still better idea is to switch from RC1 to  RTM.
Use the below links:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html